# Plot Levels in a heatmap with ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have a dataframe with several samples in the first column and a factor in the second with 22 levels.
Example output of head(df):

```
  Sample    Chromosome
1  Sample2         chr10
2  Sample2         chr9
3  Sample3         chr10
4  Sample3         chr20
5  Sample3         chr10
6  Sample1         chr1
```

Since it is a lot of data for normal plots I intended to do a heatmap of the distribution of chr10 per sample. E.g Sample2 occurs 2000 times on chr10.

I was hoping, that ggplot would maybe accept the chr-factor with its levels as a scale but it did not.

Here is what I tried:

```
ggplot(GenomereportTrim,aes(Sample,Chromosome))+
  geom_tile(aes(fill=Chromosome),color = "white")+
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "white",high = "steelblue")
```

There are about 50 unique samples which have some distribution over the 22 levels of the chromosome factor.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: `ggplot(GenomereportTrim,aes(Sample,Chromosome)) + stat_density_2d(geom = "raster", aes(fill = ..density..), contour = FALSE)`?

Comment: Unfortunatly returns an error: `Computation failed in `stat_density2d()`:
bandwidths must be strictly positive`

Comment: I’m not exactly clear on what you want: do you want a heatmap with samples on one axis and chromosomes on the other, and the colour corresponding to the frequency with which chromosome is in each sample?

Comment: Sorry for the unclear description: I want a heatmap samples x chromosomes, where the colour (gradient) corresponds to the count of how often a sample was found on the given chromosome. Say Sample 1 was found 300 times on chr1 and 500 times on chr3 , sample 4 was found 500 times on chr20, 50 times on chr1 and 600 times on chr19. I hope this makes it clearer. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want a Sample×Chromosome plot with fill colour corresponding to the count of samples per chromosome. This is easily achieved by using a 2D binning statistic:

```
ggplot(data) +
    aes(Sample, Chromosome) +
    geom_bin2d()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help it worked perfectly. Is there way to adjust the gradient scale ?

Comment: @chrys Sure. Adjust in what sense? You can check out the `scale_fill_{continuous,manual,brewer}` functions in the documentation. There are tons of customisations you can do, including the colour scheme, the limits, breaks etc.

Comment: I wanted to give the scale a wider range since. E.g a count of 500 is not clearly distinguishable from a 2000 because it is in the same color spectrum. In a plot I would say add more ticks.